# How do I create a map from two arrays in elixir?

Tags: list, dictionary, elixir, transformation

Hi I am pretty new to Elixir

And I am not able to create a map out of tow lists which is explained below

I have two Lists and want to transform the data into map as shown below

```
rows_array = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4' ]

data_arrays = [
  [c1, v11, v12, v13, v14],
  [c2, v21, v22, v23, v24],
  [c3, v31, v32, v33, v34],
  [c4, v41, v42, v43, v44],
  [c5, v51, v52, v53, v54]
]
```

I want to create a map like the one given below

```
%{
  "R1": %{c1: v11, c2: v21, c3: v31, c4: v41, c5: c51},
  "R2": %{c1: v12, c2: v22, c3: v32, c4: v42, c5: c52},
  "R3": %{c1: v13, c2: v23, c3: v33, c4: v43, c5: c53},
  "R4": %{c1: v14, c2: v24, c3: v34, c4: v44, c5: c54},
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work.
Please note that [Enum.zip_with/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip_with/3) is new since 1.12, but you can accomplish the same with `Enum.zip` then `Enum.map`.

```
empty_rows = Enum.map(rows_array, fn _ -> %{} end)

rows =
  Enum.reduce(data_arrays, empty_rows, fn [column_name | values], rows_acc ->
    Enum.zip_with(values, rows_acc, fn value, row ->
      Map.put(row, column_name, value)
    end)
  end)

result = Enum.zip(rows_array, rows) |> Map.new()
```

Also, I kept your variable names, but please note that these are all linked lists and not arrays. Erlang ships with an `:array` module but it rarely used in practice.